# How to convert the period in a decimal value to something more URL friendly with Regex for news stories

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, seo, substring

All I am trying to figure out is a way to convert the period in a decimal to be -point- for SEO purposes.  I was trying a Regex.Replace like:

`Regex.Replace(URLVariableString, "[\d][.][\d]", "-point-")`

The only problem with this is that it replaces the numbers to the left and right.  So, can this easily but done with a better Regex pattern or am I going to have to create a substring hunting algorithm?

It doesn't matter to me if the answer is in VB or C#, I can always convert the code if needed.

One example could be a story title like: "Dollar Tree to buy Family Dollar for about $8.5 billion" and converting it to: "Dollar-Tree-to-buy-Family-Dollar-for-about-8-point-5-billion" to put in a URL to help with indexing.

Comment: Can you post some sample data you want to convert and the result you need?

Comment: @Joe it's unclear, an example would be better.

Comment: I'll edit the post shortly with an example.

Comment: Ok, an example is in the original question.  If you need more clarification, I will be glad to try to provide some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this,

```
string str = "Dollar Tree to buy Family Dollar for about $8.5 billion";
string remove = Regex.Replace(str, @" ", "-");
string result = Regex.Replace(remove, @"^(.*?)\$(\d+)\.(\d+)\b(.*)$", "$1$2-point-$3$4");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/9B6hnV)

Comment: I actually simplified 
`Regex.Replace(remove, @"^(.*?)\$(\d+)\.(\d+)\b(.*)$", "$1$2-point-$3$4");` 
to  
`Regex.Replace(remove, "(\d+)\.(\d+)", "$1-point-$2")` because the first version did not seem to work in all cases.  In order to be flexible, I am only concerned about the numbers directly to the left and right of the period.

It was the $1 type usage that I was missing to make this work.  With that piece of the puzzle I was able to get the rest, thanks!

Comment: Also note, the second version that I am now using is in VB to avoid any confusion since your answer is in C#.

Comment: Yes, this solution is exactly the type of technique I was looking for.  I only needed to add 1 line of code to the existing algorithm since I had the rest.  I knew there had to be something simple like the $1,$2 that I was missing having seen something similar in different regex usages in the past.  I just couldn't easily find an example of how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do?

```
URLVariableString.Replace(".","-point-")
```

Or maybe I am misunderstanding the question

[String replace reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The periods are used for other things like abbreviations in names and such.  That would be an easy way but it isn't suitable in this case.

Comment: @JoeBless have you considered using underscores or other characters as alternative delimiters?

Comment: I could just convert all periods to be an underscore or a dash but I was trying to see if this idea was possible and efficient first.  I really wouldn't be losing a whole lot by just doing that but converting them a -point- in some cases might be better for searches.  The key word is might...

Comment: @JoeBless I find that quite often people see regex as a magic wand which to a a master they can be but I tend to use them as a last resort cause I find that avoiding them makes for simpler more maintainable code

Comment: Yes, giant regex strings start to look like hieroglyphics really quick and can take a while to find problems with them.  I'm sure that this can be done with finding the dots and using substring commands to hunt back and fourth and check to make sure that the characters before and after are numbers but if there is a better more efficient way to do this, I would prefer it.  Also, there is no way to become a master without lots of practice so, there is no point in giving up easily on something without giving it a good try or two.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like

```
//Split the sentence into an array of words
String sArray[] = input.Split(' ');
String holder = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Decimal outD;
//Foreach word in the sentence, replace the decimal to 'point' 
//if the word is a decimal, else keep the word as is. Also add space back in.
Foreach (string s in sArray)
{
  holder = Regex.Replace(s, "[^.0-9]", "");
  if(Decimal.tryparse(holder, outD))
  {
      sb.Append(s.Replace(".","-point-"));
  }
  else
  {
      sb.Append(s);
  }
  sb.Append(' ');
}
```

Comment: Where would I use the URLVariableString string using your code?  Would I just set `sArray[] = URLVariableString;` or something like that?

Comment: No, you would replace 'input' with URLVariableString. Re-reading your question you would also change the first input.split(' ') into URLVariableString.Split('-'); in order to split on the dash instead of the spaces and then the last sb.Append(' ') changed to sb.Append('-') in order to put the dashes back in that you removed during the split operation.

Comment: This definitely works.  It is more complicated than the first answer I tried and sadly, I can't mark them both as answers or even upvote them both because I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: What I went with in VB is:
`Dim sArray As String() = input.Split("-")
        Dim holder As String = ""
        Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
        Dim outD As Decimal
        For Each s In sArray
            holder = Regex.Replace(s, "[^.0-9]", "")
            If (Decimal.TryParse(holder, outD)) Then
                sb.Append(s.Replace(".", "-point-"))
            Else
                sb.Append(s)
            End If
            sb.Append("-")
        Next
        output = sb.ToString()`
And this uses your suggestion to convert the spaces to dashes.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: I just wanted you to know that the code worked and to notify you of that since other commentors do not get notifications by default.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yeah the other code is shorter, I don't care for long regex though because it can be difficult to maintain. You never know if your project is going to be handed to someone else with a weaker grasp of regex than you so I try to keep it to a minimum. Good luck.

Comment: If you didn't notice the comments of that answer, I was actually able to shorten and improve the use of the code to be: `Regex.Replace(remove, "(\d+)\.(\d+)", "$1-point-$2")` which is not only more reliable to accomplish what I need it to but is very simple for somebody to understand.  Also, I separate out regex commands into multiple statements sometimes for readability because of how confusing it can get fast.  Thanks again.

Comment: I see, your change is much easier to read than the original. Good work.